# Why is this class not comparing equal to a string when it should?

Tags: c#, string, dictionary, unity-game-engine, overriding

I have a class that essentially wraps a string so that I can make a custom editor for this class easily. I want this class to act as if it is a string when comparing to other classes. I am using this class as a key in a Dictionary, yet when using the TryGetKey method it returns false even when both TilemapID's id strings are the same.

This is what I have:

```cs
[System.Serializable]
public sealed class TilemapID
{
    public static readonly string[] ID_LIST = new string[] { "base", "foreground", "background" };

    public string id;

    public TilemapID(string id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return id;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return id.GetHashCode();
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return id.Equals(obj);
    }

    public static explicit operator string(TilemapID id) => id.id;
    public static explicit operator TilemapID(string s)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ID_LIST.Length; i++)
        {
            if (ID_LIST[i].Equals(s))
                return new TilemapID(ID_LIST[i]);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

I can verify through the Visual Studio Debugger that both this "id" and another TilemapID's "id" are the same:
[Both maps[q].id & savedTiles[0].id are the same.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9tn4.png)

I've tried to step through visual studio with the debugger, and when it gets to the part shown in the screenshot it goes to the GetHashCode method, then the Equals method, which returns false, so it skips over `grabbed = g` and goes to `else continue`. Shouldn't it actually go to `grabbed = g` because I overrode the Equals and GetHashCode methods, which should return true?

Comment: Your current code works perfectly fine. I tested it. You have shown us the code for `TilemapID` (which works perfectly fin as-is) but you haven't shown us how you're using it. You've just made the assertion that two variables (in code you haven't shown) are equal. There is not enough here to answer your question. The fact you've marked the current answer as accepted is unusual.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since I was using my class as a key in a dictionary, when I would try to access a value with an instance of this class it would not be equal to any keys. Changing the Equals method to this fixes that problem:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
  return id == obj.ToString();
}
```

Comment: This is dependant on the object passed in. You could get false positives.

Comment: The problem you are facing is not in the code that you presented, but the code you didn't. If you really want to solve this problem and understand where your code went wrong, please post the full code.

Comment: @Enigmativity as I said many many times, accessing a value through a dictionary.

Comment: Please post the full code. I don't know what it really looks like until I see it. You telling me that you're "accessing a value through a dictionary" doesn't help me to understand where you're going wrong. It's clear that you're passing the wrong value through to the `Equals` method, but where I can't tell without the code. And until then this question is of limited value to future readers (which is the purpose of this site).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Enigmativity I already solved it. This answer was correct and I'm not sure why it's downvoted or why you said it's not the correct answer.

Comment: It's downvoted because it relies on the `.ToString()` overload of the type you're passing in to give you equality. But you could pass any object that **happens to produce the same string** and it would think it's equal. This is a terrible answer. The correct answer would come from fixing the calling code and making sure your object correctly calls `Equals`.

Comment: @Enigmativity for the last time, I'm getting a value from a dictionary.

Comment: @Heroshrine - It doesn't help knowing that you're passing from a dictionary. Whatever you're doing, you're passing the wrong type. You need to show your full code so I can show you why what you're doing is wrong and why this solution appears to work.